# ActiveRecord Query Union

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, union, active-relation

I've written a couple of complex queries (at least to me) with Ruby on Rail's query interface:

```
watched_news_posts = Post.joins(:news => :watched).where(:watched => {:user_id => id})
watched_topic_posts = Post.joins(:post_topic_relationships => {:topic => :watched}).where(:watched => {:user_id => id})
```

Both of these queries work fine by themselves.  Both return Post objects.  I would like to combine these posts into a single ActiveRelation.  Since there could be hundreds of thousands of posts at some point, this needs to be done at the database level.  If it were a MySQL query, I could simply user the `UNION` operator.  Does anybody know if I can do something similar with RoR's query interface?

Comment: You should be able to use [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope). Create 2 scopes and then call them both like `Post.watched_news_posts.watched_topic_posts`. You may need to send in params to the scopes for things like the `:user_id` and `:topic`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  According to the docs, "A scope represents a narrowing of a database query".  In my case, I'm not looking for posts that are in both watched_news_posts and watched_topic_posts.  Rather, I'm looking for posts that are in watched_news_posts or watched_topic_posts, with no duplicates allowed.  Is this still possible to accomplish with scopes?

Comment: Not really possible out-of-the-box. There is a plugin on github called union but it uses old-school syntax (class method and hash-style query params), if that's cool with you I'd say go with it... otherwise write it out the long way in a find_by_sql in your scope.

Comment: I agree with jenjenut233, and I would think you could do something like `find_by_sql("#{watched_news_posts.to_sql} UNION #{watched_topic_posts.to_sql}")`.  I haven't tested that out, so let me know how it goes if you try it.  Also, there's probably some ARel functionality that would work.

Comment: Well I rewrote the queries as SQL queries.  They work now, but unfortunately `find_by_sql` can't be used with other chainable queries, which means I now have to rewrite my will_paginate filters and queries as well.  Why doesn't ActiveRecord support a `union` operation?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with a left outer join

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Here's a quick little module I wrote that allows you to UNION multiple scopes.  It also returns the results as an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation.

```
module ActiveRecord::UnionScope
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def union_scope(*scopes)
      id_column = "#{table_name}.id"
      sub_query = scopes.map { |s| s.select(id_column).to_sql }.join(" UNION ")
      where "#{id_column} IN (#{sub_query})"
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/tlowrimore/5162327

#### Edit:

As requested, here's an example of how UnionScope works:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::UnionScope

  # some silly, contrived scopes
  scope :active_nearby,     -> { where(active: true).where('distance <= 25') }
  scope :inactive_distant,  -> { where(active: false).where('distance >= 200') }

  # A union of the aforementioned scopes
  scope :active_near_and_inactive_distant, -> { union_scope(active_nearby, inactive_distant) }
end
```

Comment: This is really a way more complete answer the other others listed above.  Works great!

Comment: Example of usage would be nice.

Comment: As requested, I've added an example.

Comment: I get an exception with SQLite: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression.

Comment: @SarahVessels That error seems to imply that the nested select statements are querying more than one column; however, the `union_scope` definition explicitly selects the `id` column and nothing more.  I'd be curious to see what the resulting SQL is for your scenario.  Have you tried calling `to_sql` on your scope to see what the generated SQL looks like?

Comment: The solution is "almost" correct and I gave it a +1, but I ran into a problem that I fixed here: https://gist.github.com/lsiden/260167a4d3574a580d97

Comment: Quick warning: this method is highly problematic from a performance perspective with MySQL, since the subquery will be counted as dependent and executed for each record in the table (see http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/).

Answer (score 87):

I also have encountered this problem, and now my go-to strategy is to generate SQL (by hand or using `to_sql` on an existing scope) and then stick it in the `from` clause.  I can't guarantee it's any more efficient than your accepted method, but it's relatively easy on the eyes and gives you a normal ARel object back.

```
watched_news_posts = Post.joins(:news => :watched).where(:watched => {:user_id => id})
watched_topic_posts = Post.joins(:post_topic_relationships => {:topic => :watched}).where(:watched => {:user_id => id})

Post.from("(#{watched_news_posts.to_sql} UNION #{watched_topic_posts.to_sql}) AS posts")
```

You can do this with two different models as well, but you need to make sure they both "look the same" inside the UNION -- you can use `select` on both queries to make sure they will produce the same columns.

```
topics = Topic.select('user_id AS author_id, description AS body, created_at')
comments = Comment.select('author_id, body, created_at')

Comment.from("(#{comments.to_sql} UNION #{topics.to_sql}) AS comments")
```

Comment: suppose if we have two different model  then please let me know what will be the query for unoin.

Comment: Very helpful answer. For future readers, remember the final "AS comments" portion because activerecord constructs the query as 'SELECT "comments"."*" FROM"... if you don't specify the name of the unioned set OR specify a different name like "AS foo", the final sql execution will fail.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I extended ActiveRecord::Relation to support `#or` in my Rails 4 project. Assuming same model: `klass.from("(#{to_sql} union #{other_relation.to_sql}) as #{table_name}")`

Comment: Would be possible to have a third model (without a real table) to work like an uniform "interface" for the first two models? Eg. Wine and Soda, and a thrid model called Drink, which will union the first two for query only purpose.

Answer (score 11):

Based on Olives' answer, I did come up with another solution to this problem.  It feels a little bit like a hack, but it returns an instance of `ActiveRelation`, which is what I was after in the first place.

```
Post.where('posts.id IN 
      (
        SELECT post_topic_relationships.post_id FROM post_topic_relationships
          INNER JOIN "watched" ON "watched"."watched_item_id" = "post_topic_relationships"."topic_id" AND "watched"."watched_item_type" = "Topic" WHERE "watched"."user_id" = ?
      )
      OR posts.id IN
      (
        SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "news" ON "news"."id" = "posts"."news_id" 
        INNER JOIN "watched" ON "watched"."watched_item_id" = "news"."id" AND "watched"."watched_item_type" = "News" WHERE "watched"."user_id" = ?
      )', id, id)
```

I'd still appreciate it if anybody has any suggestions to optimize this or improve the performance, because it's essentially executing three queries and feels a little redundant.

Comment: How could I do the same thing with this: https://gist.github.com/2241307  So that it creates an AR::Relation class rather than an Array class?

Answer (score 11):

You could also use [Brian Hempel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418591/brian-hempel)'s [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem that extends `ActiveRecord` with an `union` method for scopes.

Your query would be like this:

```
Post.joins(:news => :watched).
  where(:watched => {:user_id => id}).
  union(Post.joins(:post_topic_relationships => {:topic => :watched}
    .where(:watched => {:user_id => id}))
```

Hopefully this will be eventually merged into `ActiveRecord` some day.

Answer (score 6):

Could you use an OR instead of a UNION?

Then you could do something like:

```
Post.joins(:news => :watched, :post_topic_relationships => {:topic => :watched})
.where("watched.user_id = :id OR topic_watched.user_id = :id", :id => id)
```

(Since you are joins the watched table twice I'm not too sure what the names of the tables will be for the query)

Since there are a lot of joins, it might also be quite heavy on the database, but it might be able to be optimized.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, but I've been on vacation for the last couple days.  The problem I had when I tried your answer was the joins method was causing both tables to be joined, rather than two separate queries which could then be compared.  However, your idea was sound and did give me another idea.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: select using OR is slower than than UNION, wondering any solution for UNION instead

Answer (score 6):

Arguably, this improves readability, but not necessarily performance:

```
def my_posts
  Post.where <<-SQL, self.id, self.id
    posts.id IN 
    (SELECT post_topic_relationships.post_id FROM post_topic_relationships
    INNER JOIN watched ON watched.watched_item_id = post_topic_relationships.topic_id 
    AND watched.watched_item_type = "Topic" 
    AND watched.user_id = ?
    UNION
    SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN news ON news.id = posts.news_id 
    INNER JOIN watched ON watched.watched_item_id = news.id 
    AND watched.watched_item_type = "News" 
    AND watched.user_id = ?)
  SQL
end
```

This method returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, so you could call it like this:

```
my_posts.order("watched_item_type, post.id DESC")
```

Comment: where are you getting posts.id from?

Comment: There are two self.id parameters because self.id is referenced twice in the SQL -- see the two question marks.

Comment: This was a useful example of how to do a a UNION query and get back an ActiveRecord::Relation. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a tool to generate these types of SDL queries - how did you do it without spelling mistakes etc.?

Answer (score 6):

How about...

```
def union(scope1, scope2)
  ids = scope1.pluck(:id) + scope2.pluck(:id)
  where(id: ids.uniq)
end
```

Comment: Be warned that this will perform three queries rather than one, as each `pluck` call is a query in itself.

Comment: This is a really good solution, becouse it doesn't return an array, so then you can use `.order` or `.paginate` methods... It keeps the orm classes

Comment: Useful if the scopes are of the same model, but this would generate two queries because of the plucks.

Comment: Likewise this worked great for me, much simpler than the other approaches, and I can chain more scopes on!

Comment: how pagination will work in this?

Answer (score 3):

There is an active_record_union gem.
Might be helpful

https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union

> With ActiveRecordUnion, we can do:
>
> the current user's (draft) posts and all published posts from anyone
> `current_user.posts.union(Post.published)`
> Which is equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT "posts".* FROM (
  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."user_id" = 1
  UNION
  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (published_at < '2014-07-19 16:04:21.918366')
) posts
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use SQL syntax inside your code, here's solution with `arel`

```rb
watched_news_posts = Post.joins(:news => :watched).where(:watched => {:user_id => id}).arel
watched_topic_posts = Post.joins(:post_topic_relationships => {:topic => :watched}).where(:watched => {:user_id => id}).arel

results = Arel::Nodes::Union.new(watched_news_posts, watched_topic_posts)
from(Post.arel_table.create_table_alias(results, :posts))
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case I summed two arrays and used `Kaminari:paginate_array()`. Very nice and working solution. I was unable to use `where()`, because I need to sum two results with different `order()` on the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I joined SQL queries using UNION on my own ruby on rails application.

You can use the below as inspiration on your own code.

```
class Preference < ApplicationRecord
  scope :for, ->(object) { where(preferenceable: object) }
end
```

Below is the UNION where i joined the scopes together.

```
  def zone_preferences
    zone = Zone.find params[:zone_id]
    zone_sql = Preference.for(zone).to_sql
    region_sql = Preference.for(zone.region).to_sql
    operator_sql = Preference.for(Operator.current).to_sql

    Preference.from("(#{zone_sql} UNION #{region_sql} UNION #{operator_sql}) AS preferences")
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Less problems and easier to follow:

```rb
    def union_scope(*scopes)
      scopes[1..-1].inject(where(id: scopes.first)) { |all, scope| all.or(where(id: scope)) }
    end
```

So in the end:

```rb
union_scope(watched_news_posts, watched_topic_posts)
```

Comment: I changed it slightly to: `scopes.drop(1).reduce(where(id: scopes.first)) { |query, scope| query.or(where(id: scope)) }` Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'active_record_extended'
```

Also has a set of `union` helpers among many others.

Answer (score 0):

I would just run the two queries you need and combine the arrays of records that are returned:

```
@posts = watched_news_posts + watched_topics_posts
```

Or, at the least test it out.  Do you think the array combination in ruby will be far too slow?  Looking at the suggested queries to get around the problem, I'm not convinced that there will be that significant of a performance difference.

Comment: Actually doing @posts=watched_news_posts & watched_topics_posts might be better as it is an intersection and will avoid dupes.

Comment: I was under the impression ActiveRelation loads its records lazily.  Wouldn't you lose that if you intersected the arrays in Ruby?

Comment: Apparently a union which returns a relation is under dev in rails, but I don't know what version it will be in.

Comment: this return array instead, its two different query results merge.

Answer (score 0):

Elliot Nelson answered good, except the case where some of the relations are empty. I would do something like that:

```
def union_2_relations(relation1,relation2)
sql = ""
if relation1.any? && relation2.any?
  sql = "(#{relation1.to_sql}) UNION (#{relation2.to_sql}) as #{relation1.klass.table_name}"
elsif relation1.any?
  sql = relation1.to_sql
elsif relation2.any?
  sql = relation2.to_sql
end
relation1.klass.from(sql)
```

end

Answer (score 0):

When we add UNION to the scopes, it breaks at time due to order_by clause added before the UNION.

So I changed it in a way to give it a UNION effect.

```
module UnionScope
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def union_scope(*scopes)
      id_column = "#{table_name}.id"
      sub_query = scopes.map { |s| s.pluck(:id) }.flatten
      where("#{id_column} IN (?)", sub_query)
    end
  end
end
```

And then use it like this in any model

```
class Model
  include UnionScope
  scope :union_of_scopeA_scopeB, -> { union_scope(scopeA, scopeB) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is great. It uses the ids of the scopes in the `WHERE` clause. As shosti reports, this method is problematic in terms of performance because all ids need to be generated during query execution. This is why, I prefer joeyk16 answer. Here a generalized module:

```
module ActiveRecord::UnionScope
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def self.union(*scopes)
      self.from("(#{scopes.map(&:to_sql).join(' UNION ')}) AS #{self.table_name}")
    end 
  end
end
```