# rails way to fetch records from same table with different types

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relational-database

I want to fetch three types of tickets from same table Ticket. Like this

```
Ticket.where(type: 'a').limit(5)
Ticket.where(type: 'b').limit(5)
Ticket.where(type: 'c').limit(5)
```

What is the  best way in rails to get data equivalent to above three queries with minimum DB hits.

Comment: I want 15 records including 5 records of each type "a","b"and "c".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use sql UNION query. You can see this answers:
[ActiveRecord Query Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union)

Or made all that things using just rails's sum. It's not elegant solution, but you can try that:

```
scope :by_type, ->(type){ where(type: type).limit(5) }

def self.foo
  Ticket.by_type('a') + Ticket.by_type('b') + Ticket.by_type('c')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`IN`**

```
types = [a,b,c]

Ticket.where("type IN (?)", types).limit(5)
```

Comment: It will give us 5 records  but we need 5 records of each type. SO in total 15.

Comment: @AdnanAli Interesting.Totally missed that point.Will keep goggling on that.