# Merge has_many and has_many through queries together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

This seems like a typical problem, but it is difficult to search for.

I want to select projects that a user owns via a `has_many` and projects that a user is associated to via a `has_many through`.

Consider the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects,
           inverse_of: :owner

  has_many :project_associations,
           class_name: 'ProjectUser',
           inverse_of: :user

  has_many :associated_projects,
           through: :project_associations,
           source: :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner,
             class_name: 'User',
             foreign_key: :owner_id,
             inverse_of: :projects

  has_many :user_associations,
           class_name: 'ProjectUser',
           inverse_of: :project

  has_many :associated_users,
           through: :user_associations,
           source: :user
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project,
             inverse_of: :user_associations

  belongs_to :user,
             inverse_of: :project_associations
end
```

It is trivial to do this with multiple queries:

```
user = User.find(1)
all_projects = user.projects + user.associated_projects
```

But I suspect it could be optimised using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) into a single query.

---

**Edit:**

My first attempt at a solution using the `find_by_sql` method is:

```
Project.find_by_sql([
  'SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ' \
  'INNER JOIN "project_users" ' \
  'ON "projects"."id" = "project_users"."project_id" ' \
  'WHERE "project_users"."user_id" = :user_id ' \
  'OR "projects"."owner_id" = :user_id',
  { user_id: 1 }
])
```

This produces the result I am expecting, but I would like to avoid using `find_by_sql` and instead let Arel build the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Project.joins(:user_associations)
       .where("projects.owner_id = ? OR project_users.user_id = ?", id, id)
```

You could put that in a method called `User#all_projects`.

You could also use [`UNION`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union), although it seems like overkill here.

Just one warning: In my experience this structure of two alternate paths to connect your models, where one path is a join table and the other is a direct foreign key, causes a lot of trouble. You're going to have to deal with both cases all the time, and in complex queries the `OR` can confuse the database query planner. If you're able to, you might want to reconsider. I think you will have fewer headaches if you remove the `owner_id` column and identify owners with a `role` column on `project_users` instead.

**EDIT** or in Arel:

```
Project.joins(:user_associations)
       .where(Project.arel_table[:owner_id].eq(id).or(
              ProjectUser.arel_table[:user_id].eq(id)))
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this will work, but for the solution I am looking for a way to use Arel without touching sql directly. I understand the double association can cause problems, but at this point refactoring is not an option (at least for a while).

Comment: Okay added an Arel version. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `includes` directive as in:

```
User.includes(:projects, :associated_projects).find(1)
```

Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Then if you call `projects` and `associated_projects` on the found instance you'll not fire additional queries.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. This just pre-caches the result set of `projects` and `associated_projects`, and is done in multiple queries. I am looking for a single query that produces a single result set of `projects` that the user owns and is associated to.

Comment: AFAIK `includes` uses `join` whenever possible, so it'd be one single query.

Comment: Unfortunately not. What will be returned from your example is a single `user` row. It performs a query on the `project_users` table to fetch the project ids (1st query), a query on the `projects` table with the `owner_id` (2nd query) and another query on the `projects` table where id in project ids from the 1st query. Total queries = 3. Regardless of the number of queries performed, the result is not what I am looking for. I need a AR `CollectionProxy` of `Projects` that are associated to the user, through `owner_id` and the association model.

Answer (score 0):

I have my solution, the model structure remains the same, and I add a method on the `User` model called `all_projects`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects,
           inverse_of: :owner

  has_many :project_associations,
           class_name: 'ProjectUser',
           inverse_of: :user

  has_many :associated_projects,
           through: :project_associations,
           source: :project

  def all_projects
    query = Project.arel_table[:owner_id].eq(id).or(ProjectUser.arel_table[:user_id].eq(id))
    Project.joins(:user_associations).where(query)
  end
end
```

Calling `#all_projects` builds and executes this query:

```
SELECT "projects".*
FROM "projects"
INNER JOIN "project_users" ON "project_users"."project_id" = "products"."id"
WHERE ("projects"."owner_id" = '1' OR "project_users"."user_id" = '1')
```

The solution isn't as elegant as I would like, ideally I would like to replace `Project.arel_table[:owner_id].eq(id)` with the query that is built from the `has_many projects` association, adding the `.or(ProjectUser.arel_table[:user_id].eq(id))` onto it, but this works well for now.