# How to merge multiple and different ActiveRecord query in rails and paginate over the records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I have two similar tables in rails named as messages and message_histories. Periodically we remove the old data from messages table and drop it in message_histories .

Now , I want to generate a report on the count of messages grouped by app_id which is present in message and message_history table .

Is there a way to Query [**Message** & **MessageHistory** ] Model and paginate on the records .

Currently I use the following Step , It looks weird but suggest a better way to do this :

```
@messages = Message.select("SUM(devices_count) as count ,CAST(run_at AS DATE) AS date").where(:app_id => @app.id).where("last_run_date is not ?", nil).group("CAST(run_at AS DATE)").order("date desc")
@messages << MessageHistory.select("SUM(devices_count) as count ,CAST(run_at AS DATE) AS date").where(:app_id => @app.id).where("last_run_date is not ?", nil).group("CAST(run_at AS DATE)").order("date desc")
@messages = @messages.flatten.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 100)
```

Comment: Not aware of a neat way to do this rails way but you can go for `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute()` and run the query over both tables

Comment: you can do something like `polymorphic association` for messages history as it is one form of  messages. no need a second table for message histories

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to `UNION` the two tables, then paginate the results.

See [ActiveRecord Query Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union) for some examples, and look at the [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem (which makes it easier to do UNIONs with ActiveRecord).

It will take some experimentation to figure out how to apply the where clause filters and sums/groups properly!