# How to convert this query into active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to convert this query into the active record but don't get any luck. Can anyone guide me how to convert this query from raw SQL to active record query

```
select users.* from
    (
    select email from players_schema.inv_emails where inv_emails.created_at <= (current_date - interval '14 days')
    union
    select email from players_schema.blks where blks.created_at <= (current_date - interval '14 days')
    union
    select email from players_schema.bouces where bouces.created_at <= (current_date - interval '14 days')
    ) email
    join football_schema.users on users.email = email.email;
```

I am using rails 4.2

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution

```
User.from("(#{players_schema.inv_emails.to_sql} UNION # 
{players_schema.bouces.to_sql} UNION #{players_schema.blks.to_sql} ) 
AS invalid_emails").joins("INNER join football_schema.users on 
users.email = invalid_emails.email")
```