# Where ActiveRecord query return empty AssociationRelation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to make a query where results be added to array, example:

#### app/models/user.rb

```
query = self.patients.where(["created_at >= ? and created_at >= ? and created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.beginning_of_week, Time.now.beginning_of_month]).to_a
```

#### Expected result:

```
query
=> [3, 5, 12]
```

#### Current result:

```
Patient Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `patients`.* FROM `patients` WHERE `patients`.`medic_id` = 1 AND (created_at >= '2018-07-20 00:00:00' and created_at >= '2018-07-16 05:00:00' and created_at >= '2018-07-01 05:00:00')
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>

without to_a method => [#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>]
with to_a method => []
```

#### Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :patients, dependent: :destroy
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am recieving a empty array/AssociationRelation, how can I get the array with the count of patients for beginning of the day, week, month, like this `query = [3, 5, 12]`?

Note, using:

- Mysql: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using
  readline 5.1
- Ruby: 2.3.3p222
- Rails: 5.0.0.1
- ActiveRecord: 5.0.0.1

Comment: This isn't how ActiveRecord works. You can't return these values with a single `select`, you need three sub-queries.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  scope :created_since, -> (time) { where('created_at >= ?', time) }
  # ...
end
```

### Example:

> how can I get the array with the count of patients for beginning of the day, week, month, like this query = [3, 5, 12]?

```
patients_counts = [
  Patient.created_since(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).count,
  Patient.created_since(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week).count,
  Patient.created_since(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month).count,
]

puts patients_counts
# => [3, 5, 12]
```

- Just in case you don't know, you can also do it like: `@user.patients.created_since(...)`

*P.S. I do not suggest doing in one query, and just do three separate count queries like above. You can do it in one query but you'll have to write a very specific SQL, and will get ugly because you'll need three subqueries (from what I can see).*

Comment: Why not use one scope and pass the time?

Comment: I think you could do with one subquery using a case statement?  I normally use tsql (sql server) so I'm not exactly sure on the syntax but something like: `"SELECT SUM(q.today) AS today, SUM(q.week) AS week, SUM(q.month) AS month FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN created_at >= ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS today, CASE WHEN created_at >= ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS week, CASE WHEN created_at >= ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS month) AS q"`.  That's definitely pretty nasty though for activerecord but you could maybe frankenstein it with arel.

Comment: ohh I've never thought of it doing this way. Interesting... Although, do you not think this would be slower than counting the three subqueries? I am not well versed in SQL, but it seems to me that the CASE WHEN applies a logic for each row, and so I was just wondering that it would make it slow? I'll try yours later; I'm curious to see :D

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario thanks, it works perfect, if I wanted to reduce the number of queries to the database then I would have to make the query in raw sql?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I'm not sure.  The count probably changes the sql query to be something like `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE created_at > ?` which I imagine is gonna be pretty fast and depending on the server probably can re-use the execution plan for the three counts.  Either way I think you'd definitely want to put an index on the created_at column? I'd be curious to see some benchmarks between the two approaches.

Comment: Ahh yeah, perhaps the database can easily optimise the query. Yes, I think so too that `created_at` column would need an index if this is not gonna be just a once-off code that Carlos would use :)

Comment: @CarlosGómez yes, I believe so. The expected result of your query is an Array of integers (i.e. `[3, 5, 12]`), but if you are gonna be using `ActiveRecord`, the expected will be an Array of/single `record` objects. Having said that though, `ActiveRecord` supports `.count`, `.exists?`, `.group`, .etc... You can combine `.count` and `.group` to get a resulting value like (i.e. grouping by `first_name`) `{'Jake': 5, 'Trisha': 2}`, but for your specific case, I don't think you can group by a "range of created_at time since x"...

Comment: @CarlosGómez ...but if you come up with something, let me know; I'm interested :D [See some of the docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html), in particular `count`. And oh, there's also the `arel`, of which I believe you can do this because arel is like the lower-level form of `ActiveRecord`, and that actually `ActiveRecord` is built on top of it. If you feel like exploring; [here's some basics that I usually always look back again, every now and then](https://devhints.io/arel)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario thank you man I appreciate your help, I will check the docs

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use SQL `UNION` operator to combine 3 different sets of records filtered by different timestamps. You can read how to achieve such result in this post: [ActiveRecord Query Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union)